# android java InputStream :InputStream.availableの値が異常。

Tags: android, java, android-studio

MIDIファイルのデータを処理するアプリを作成中で、リソースのMIDIファイルを`InputStream`
で読み込んで、一応動作したのですが、SDカードのMIDIファイルを`FileInputStream`で読んで、`InputStream`にして、同じメソッドで処理しようとするとNGです。

その原因を探ると、`FileInputStream`で読んだ時点では本来のファイルバイト数だったのが、`InputStream`に変えた時点で22バイト少なくなっていることを確認しました。

原因と正常な`InputStream`を得る方法を教えてください。

```
// 略

filePath2 = cursor.getString(0);
try {
    //midM = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath2));
    fInputStream=new FileInputStream(filePath2);
    int nsize=fInputStream.available();
    midM = fInputStream;
    int msize=midM.available();
     if (nsize!=msize) {
        editedText=editedText+" fInputStream<>midM";
         midM.close();
         editText.setText(editedText);
         return;
    }

//略
```

Comment: 「22バイト少なくなっている」というのをどうやって確認したのか明確に記載すると回答が得られやすくなるのではないかと感じました。(さらに加えるなら、「`InputStream`にして」「`InputStream`に変えた」に対応する実装が想像できませんでした。コード中のコメントなどで該当するコードを指し示してもらえればより質問の意図が明確になるかと思われます。)

Comment: 「22バイト少なくなっている」というのはコードに示しているように、FileInputStreamであるfInputStreamのavailableの値と、InputStreamであるmidMのavailableの値をデバッグ時確認しました。また、各々のバイトデータの値を確認すると、どうやらInputStreamであるmidMはfInputStreamの先頭部分の22バイトがなくなっているようです。「InputS‌​treamにして」「InputStrea‌​mに変えた」に対応する実装ということの意味が初心者なのでよくわからないのですが、FileInputStreamはInputStreamからの派生クラスなので単純に コードに示してあるように midM=fInputStream としているだけです。間違っていたらご教授お願いします。（基礎から勉強しなさいと言われそうですが。。。）